# Verify user login and password over api

Tags: rest-api

I run a unique website where users can purchase live streamed video content. We're in the very early stages of building an app for Android and iOS. I'm working on our own custom api separate of WordPress because we'll need some other functions in our API.

I need to be able to verify a user on a mobile device (using an app) is authorized as a user. So I'll need to verify their login credentials over the API. It seems that WordPress has done some API updates recently, so I'm finding Google results to be all over the place.

Can anyone point me in the right direction.

My overall intent is to use the WordPress API to verify the login credentials of users, then pull their purchases from our website into our own API for reference when they're using the app. I just need to verify the user is able to login and is in fact our user, thus verifying username and password.

Thanks

Rob

Comment: WP can authenticate sessions via the API, the same way it authenticates sessions with browsers and cookies, and it does this on its own without intervention, but it can't create new sessions and log users in via the REST API, REST API authentication only works with cookie based sessions that already exist, or predefined application passwords. In addition to there being no login endpoint, there is no registration endpoint either

Comment: Well this could get rather difficult then....  This is something we're going to need to figure out. Or find a way to pass existing user data to our own database outside of WP

Comment: 3rd party plugins may provide alternative solutions, as well as other methods of authentication that might be more convenient for a mobile app, but recommendations are offtopic here, and it's not something stock vanilla WordPress provides out of the box. OAuth 2 for example